# PDF thumbnails in iPad are blurry

Tags: iphone, ipad, pdf, cgaffinetransform, cgpdfdocument

I am creating thumbnails and showing those thumbnails in gridView(using AQgridView). Thumbnails shown in gridView is too blurry and is not what I want. I am attached my code. Please help.

Here is my code:-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.gridView = [[AQGridView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
self.gridView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
self.gridView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
self.gridView.delegate = self;
self.gridView.dataSource = self;
[self.view addSubview:gridView];


[self makeThumbs];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

///////////Making thumb from PDF file///////////////

```
-(void)makeThumbs{

NSString* finalPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Maths" ofType:@"pdf" inDirectory:nil];



NSURL* pdfFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:finalPath];
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)pdfFileUrl);
CGPDFPageRef page;

CGRect aRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 100); // thumbnail size
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(aRect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();



NSUInteger totalNum = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf);

for(int i = 0; i < totalNum; i++ ) {
     UIImage* thumbnailImage;

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, aRect.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, aRect);


    // Grab the first PDF page
    page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, i + 1);
    CGAffineTransform pdfTransform = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, kCGPDFMediaBox, aRect, 0, true);
    // And apply the transform.
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, pdfTransform);

    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);

    // Create the new UIImage from the context
    thumbnailImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    //Use thumbnailImage (e.g. drawing, saving it to a file, etc)

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    [imageArray addObject:thumbnailImage];

}
NSLog(@"image array count is %d",[imageArray count]);
if ([imageArray count]>0) {
    [self.gridView reloadData];
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);
}
```

Here image showing blurry thumbnails that are created on iPad Simulator[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` passing 0.0 as scale (to use the screen scale).

Comment: UInstead of UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(aRect.size), call UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(aRect.size, NO, 0.0).

Comment: Its still blurry and code change has no impact on blurriness.